# write the given third order linear equation as an equivalent system of first order equations with initial values.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write the given third order linear equation as an equivalent system of first-order equations with initial values:

$$-(‴+3\sin(t)′) = 2t$$

with $$y(3)=−2,  y'(3)=3,  y''(3)=0$$

Use $_1=$, $_2=′$, and $_3=″$.

I was able to get $_3'$=$−(3\sin()_2)−2$. Does this mean that $x_1 = 0, x_3 =0$ but what is $x_2$ and the constant? What is the $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that :
$$\begin {cases} x_1=y \\ x_2=y'=x'_1 \\x_3=y''=x'_2 \end{cases} \implies \begin {cases} x'_1=x_2 \\ x'_2=x_3 \end{cases}  $$
And as you noted you have also that 
$$x'_3=-3\sin(t)x_2-2t$$
Therefore you can write the DE equation as :
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix}'= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -3\sin(t) & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -2t \end{pmatrix}$$
The "$t$" is the inhomogeneous part of the equation.